# how to add list values to existing dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im trying to add each values of score to the dict names i,e score[0] to names[0] and so on...

```
names=[{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'box'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'printer'}]
score = [0.9894376397132874, 0.819094657897949, 0.78116521835327]
```

Output should be like this

```
names=[{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop','score':0.98}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'box','score':0.81}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'printer','score':0.78}]
```

How to achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it with a comprehension like this:

```
>>> [{**d, 'score':s} for d, s in zip(names, score)]
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop', 'score': 0.9894376397132874}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'box', 'score': 0.819094657897949}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'printer', 'score': 0.78116521835327}]
```

Comment: i think you need names[d]

Comment: @JoranBeasley pardon?

Comment: d is just the key isnt it? maybe not i guess not since it actually looks like you ran it

Comment: @JoranBeasley `d` is a dict from the list of dicts `names`.

Comment: lol its clearly too late i need to go to bed :P ... great answer (I gave you +1 earlier)

Answer (score 2):

Without list comprehension.

```
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    name['score'] = score[i]

print(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy-to-understand solution. From your example, I understand you don't want to round up the numbers but still want to cut them.

```
import math

def truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

names=[{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'box'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'printer'}]
score = [0.9894376397132874, 0.819094657897949, 0.78116521835327]
n = len(score)
for i in range(n):
    names[i]["score"] = truncate(score[i], 2)

print(names)
```

If you do want to round up the numbers:

```
names=[{'id': 1, 'name': 'laptop'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'box'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'printer'}]
score = [0.9894376397132874, 0.819094657897949, 0.78116521835327]
n = len(score)
for i in range(n):
    names[i]["score"] = round(score[i], 2)

print(names)
```